# Unable to save and error on DBCC CHECKDB

Tags: sql-server, backup, dbcc-checkdb

I try to save my database ≈ 260 Mb

I have this error :

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError : failure read function incorrect

So I try : 
DBCC CHECKDB ('myDatabase') PHYSICAL_ONLY

I have this error :

> Msg 8921, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Stop control. An error occurred
>   while collecting the facts. Insufficient space in tempdb or
>   inconsistency of a system table. Check out the previous errors.

I have same error without PHYSICAL_ONLY but the rest seems normal

DBCC CHECKDB ('myDatabase') WITH ESTIMATEONLY :

> 9357520 Kb => 9 357,52 Mb

SELECT SUM(unallocated_extent_page_count) AS [free pages], 
(SUM(unallocated_extent_page_count)*1.0/128) AS [free space in MB]
FROM sys.dm_db_file_space_usage;

> free space in MB : 30 389 Mb

DBCC SQLPERF(LOGSPACE)

> tempbd : 
>   - Log size : 13 299 Mb
>   - Space Used (%) : 0.01%

I do not know why this does not work

Edit : When I try xcopy (database offline) I get this error :

> target volume does not support symbolic links

Comment: I don't have any backup

Comment: try to run dbcc checkdb on the system databases and share the results

Comment: @EduardoPivaral Same error on the begining : Msg 8921, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Stop control. An error occurred while collecting the facts. Insufficient space in tempdb or inconsistency of a system table. Check out the previous errors.
[..............]
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database 'myDatabase'

Comment: How much free space is on the drive where your tempdb data file is? If there is free space there, is tempdb configured for auto-growth? how much space does it add each time it grows? Is there enough free space for it to grow at least once?

Comment: @RDFozz 230Gb free on the drive, Yes tempdb is configured for auto-growth. Yes easily : Auto-grown : 5%/unlimited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my issue : since the CHECKDB did not send me anything extraordinary, I decided to export the tables one by one. And there a table did not want to be exported with exactly the same error. It was a temporary table I deleted it and now everything is working again. (Note: The DBCC TABLE was returning the same error : "An error occurred while collecting the facts. Insufficient space in tempdb or inconsistency of a system table")

Answer (score 0):

is it a physical or a virtual server? Please make a chkdsk on your filesystem where the database are stored.

Please also try a BACKUP DATABASE with CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR:

```
BACKUP DATABASE AdventureWorks2012   
 TO DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdvWorksData.bak'  
   WITH CHECKSUM, CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR;  
GO
```

More information about this here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/specify-if-backup-or-restore-continues-or-stops-after-error

Regards,
Björn

Comment: chkdsk : none error (4 disk : RAID 5) & same error with the continue_error : failure read

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to increase the size of the tempdb database:

- Open SQL Management Studio and login to your instance
- Open the following branches:
  **Database** > **System Database** > **tempdb**
- Right Click on the tempdb and in the context menu select **Properties**
- Click on the **Files** tab in the properties dialogue
- On the **tempdev.mdf** file change **Initial Size** to a larger value:
  ex. 2 MB to 15 MB.
- Close all dialogues and properties.

I am suggesting this as you might be just having a size issue with your tempdb. If the database is unable to grow, then it might result in error messages being thrown as in your question.